# Not able to get graphic LCD to work with Uno

Tags: arduino, glcd

I have an arduino uno and wanted to use the graphic LCD [JHD12864E](http://www.vishaworld.com/pdf/JHD12864E.pdf). My further plan is to port the same code to an ATmega32 or similar, but that is not the issue right now.

I am using the library suggested in the playground page here http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/GLCDks0108. The LCD has s6b0108 controller in it, and its compatible with the KS0108, on a youtube video they suggest that we use panel B for this lcd. I uploaded the sketch to the arduino but cannot for the life of me get anything to print on it. It just remains blank. What may be the problem? Have tried the troubleshooting page to no avail.

Right now I am using this sketch

```
// include the library header
include <glcd.h>

// include the Fonts
#include <fonts/allFonts.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize the GLCD 
  GLCD.Init();

 // Select the font for the default text area
  GLCD.SelectFont(System5x7);

  GLCD.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {

}
```

Here is a video of me changing contrast and nothing happening. http://youtu.be/UyCOGoCAoGA

Here are some pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using wires of the same colors is asking for trouble. Very easy to wire things incorrectly. I suggest you change color if possible. Triple verify the connections.

Comment: Gustavo is right, using different colours (or labeling if you only have one colour) also it makes it almost impossible for us to see what is gong where, making the images not very useful. A schematic, and a layout with much neater wiring would make it possible for us to help (plus you may discover a mistake in the process of rewiring things) What test equipment do you have available? Do you have a scope, logic analyser and/or multimeter? Have you measured the supply voltages and scoped the data/control lines?

Comment: I discovered this early on. I use standard red/black + different color (currently I have blue and yellow) for digital signals. MUCH easier to trace.

Comment: Maybe the Uno doesn't have enough SRAM?

Comment: you gotta use male headers soldered, not jumper wires directly connected as they do not eshtablish proper electrical connections.